# FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android

**Runs in debug apk but not released apk**

Error:

FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=Packagename cmp=Packagename/.FireBaseInstanceIdService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{6ae131d u0a219 SVC  idle change:idle|uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}